# Using PreferenceDataStore with Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I want to use `PreferenceDataStore` to fetch the settings of the user that are being saved in a Firebase database.

The set- function works like a charm, because there is no listener:

```
override fun putString(key: String?, value: String?) {
    if(key != null && value != null){
        val userId = UserUtils.getCurrentUser()?.uid.orEmpty()
        val preferencesReference = database.getReference("users/$userId/preferences")

        preferencesReference.updateChildren(HashMap<String,String>().apply {
            this.put(key,value)
        }.toMap())
    }
}
```

The get- function is a more complicated, because, as you may know, the firebase databaes gives us a callback method where the data is being returned. Is there  still a way to get the values? Do you have any ideas?

```
override fun getString(key: String?, defValue: String?): String? {
    if(key == null){
        return defValue
    }

    val userId = UserUtils.getCurrentUser()?.uid.orEmpty()
    database.getReference("users/$userId/preferences/$key").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object: ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
           //the return value is here, but i am not able to return it cause it's a listener

        }

        override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {}
    })

    return "wot";
}
```

Comment: @alex-mamo It's not a duplicate, cause I am not able to complete or add a listener to the method declaration due to the fact that the method is fixed inside the android os.

Comment: You cannot return something from the database as a result of a method. You need to create a custom callback for that.

Comment: I am aware of that. But, how do I have to do it in the Preferences then? Is there any way to let the android OS wait until the callback has been called?

Comment: I don't get it why you have marked the question as a duplicate. It clearly isn't a duplicate at all.

Comment: Anyone ever figure this out?

Comment: @rusty1996 i don't understand why my question was marked as a dupilcate because of that..

Comment: @romaneso I didn't mark it as duplicate. An answer for this would greatly benefit me too...

Comment: @rusty1996 yeah i know. it got flagged imediately after posting the question, which, in my opinion, doesn't make sense at all.